# Remove duplicates from array of arrays by the first object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays which looks like this:

```
arr = [
["Bob","USA","55"],
["Frank","Canada","20"],
["Bob","UK","35"],
["Bob","France","38"],
["Anna","Poland","22"]
]
```

I like to remove duplicate arrays which have the same value on the first position(the same name) - so I'd like to my output will look like that:

```
arr = [
["Bob","USA","55"],
["Frank","Canada","20"],
["Anna","Poland","22"]
]
```

I'm trying to do this in this way:

```
uniqueArr = []
for (var i in arr) {
if (uniqueArr.indexOf(arr[i][0]) === -1)) {
uniqueArr.push(arr[i][0])
}
```

Everything works ok - my output looks like Bob, Frank, Anna

But the problem is when I'm trying to recive whole arrays with unique value name. When I'm doing:

```
uniqueArr = []
for (var i in arr) {
if (uniqueArr.indexOf(arr[i][0]) === -1)) {
uniqueArr.push(arr[i])
}
```

My output looks exactly like the input array. Do you know where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is when you push the entire array onto `uniqueArr`, you can't just use `indexOf` on it any more because it no longer contains simple strings.

Comment: I removed `jQuery` tag because this is unrelevant here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could keep track of the `key` string in a separate array and track that instead, for example:

```
var uniqueArr = [],
    keys = []; // Create an array for storing the key values
for (var i in arr) {    
    if (keys.indexOf(arr[i][0]) === -1) {
        uniqueArr.push(arr[i]); // Push the value onto the unique array
        keys.push(arr[i][0]); // Push the key onto the 'key' array
    }
}
console.log(uniqueArr);
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vmqxax9f/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
arr = [
    ["Bob", "USA", "55"],
    ["Frank", "Canada", "20"],
    ["Bob", "UK", "35"],
    ["Bob", "France", "38"],
    ["Anna", "Poland", "22"]
]
var newArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (isInArr(newArr, arr[i]) == -1) {
        newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
}

function isInArr(checkArr, value) {
    var index = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkArr.length; i++) {
        if (checkArr[i][0] == value[0]) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

console.log(newArr)
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r981u2sq/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look atthe function unique2. It works!

```js
originalArr = [
  ["Bob", "USA", "55"],
  ["Frank", "Canada", "20"],
  ["Bob", "UK", "35"],
  ["Bob", "France", "38"],
  ["Anna", "Poland", "22"]
];

function unique(arr) {
  uniqueArr = [];
  for (var i in arr) {
    if (uniqueArr.indexOf(arr[i][0]) === -1) {
      uniqueArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return uniqueArr;
}

function unique2(arr) {
  uniqueArr = [];
  keys = [];
  for (var i in arr) {
    if (keys.indexOf(arr[i][0]) === -1) {
      uniqueArr.push(arr[i]);
      keys.push(arr[i][0]);
    }
  }
  return uniqueArr;
}



var response = document.getElementById('response');
response.textContent = JSON.stringify(unique(originalArr));

var response2 = document.getElementById('response2');
response2.textContent = JSON.stringify(unique2(originalArr));
```

```html
<h1>Your code</h1>
<div id="response"></div>

<h1>My code</h1>
<div id="response2"></div>
```